# How to change row color when drop-down list value is re-selected to default option("Select")?

Tags: drop-down-menu, colors, indexing, default

I have gridview with template field of dropdownlist in each row..All dropdownlists are set to default value "Select".when i select any value from dropdownlist it will change color of 3rd row below than it but when i re-select "Select" option the color is still there of 3rd row.i don't need it.it should be changed to default color of gridview that is white.
This is my code.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

       DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;

        int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
        int current_row_index = row.RowIndex;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            gvRow.BackColor = Color.White;

           if (gvRow.FindControl("dropdownid") != null && gvRow.RowIndex != current_row_index)
            {
                ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("dropdownid")).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
             }

             GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Red;

         }
```

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11738506/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.I made following changes to the code and its working fine.

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {

       DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        int count=0;
        int g = row.RowIndex + 3;
        int current_row_index = row.RowIndex;
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            gvRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            if (((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("dropdownid")).SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
               // GridView1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                count++;

                Response.Write("null");

            }

           if (gvRow.FindControl("dropdownid") != null && gvRow.RowIndex != current_row_index)
            {
                ((DropDownList)gvRow.FindControl("dropdownid")).SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
             }



             GridView1.Rows[g].BackColor = Color.Red;
              Response.Write("count="+count);

              if (count == 0)
              {
                  foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView1.Rows)
                  {
                      gvRow.BackColor = Color.White;

                  }

              }

         }
```